# What's the equivalent of bash's ${!ENV} in sh?

Tags: bash, sh, gitlab-ci

The command `${!ENV}` in bash will take the value of the environment variable `ENV` and then interpret that value as the name of another environment variable which it will then return the value of right after.

```
ENV=PATH
echo ${!ENV}
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

In an attempt to make an existing Gitlab Pipeline more concise, I found a use for this behaviour. However, our Gitlab runner runs things with sh, as opposed to bash.

What's the equivalent of bash's `${!ENV}` in sh?

Comment: Have a look at _indirection_ on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: The solution would be to use `eval "echo \$${ENV}"`

Comment: This is no equivalent; that's why shells add their own indirect expansion as an extension to the POSIX standard.

Comment: Using `eval` is not equivalent; its behavior is a large (and dangerous) superset of what `${!ENV}` does.

Comment: This is an XY problem; there may be another, POSIX-compliant solution for your use case than indirect parameter expansion.

Comment: Try using `printenv` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. POSIX does not mandate such an "indirect expansion" in shell. The best thing you can do is `eval` if you want to be strictly POSIX-compliant:

```
ENV=PATH
eval echo "\"$ENV is \$$ENV\""
```

Output (example):

```
PATH is /usr/bin
```

In my experience, using Bash has almost no difficulty anywhere, so you should also consider sticking to Bash unless you're pedantically POSIX.

Be aware that `eval` is a dangerous thing. You are advised to verify that the string is safe to `eval` before actually evaluating it, unless the string is created by you (your script) and not some user input. Something as simple as this will work:

```
echo "$ENV" | grep -qi '^[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*$'
```

Check the exit value `$?`. If it's zero then you can safely evaluate `$ENV`. If it's 1 then you'd better check the string more thoroughly.

Comment: if only working with Linux "Bash" is ok, but keep in mind that is not even installed by default in other operating systems (*BSD) so by using "sh" you ensure more portability

Comment: I don't know about you, but that solution looks much better than what I came up with in the last 20 minutes: `echo $(env | grep ^$(env | grep ^ENV= | cut -f2 -d"=") | cut -f2 -d"=")`. Worth noting: This only works when both variables are exported.

Comment: At least check that the value of `ENV` is actually a valid identifier name to avoid injection attacks.

Comment: I am starting to see the problems. Is my verbose solution any safer?

Comment: Safer, but far too heavyweight. You're spawning 6 external processes, in addition to the fork for the command substitution.

Comment: Something like `expr '[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*' : "$ENV" && eval "echo \"\$$ENV\""` help ensure that `eval` doesn't see anything other than a simple parameter expansion.

Comment: My solution will also fail if there are line breaks in the value.